# VBA putting String in Cell that the function is being executed in

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell that I'm trying to have display a different String depending on the input parameter but I don't understand how to return/print a String to the cell. There is no syntax error but the cell just remains blank. Here is my code :

```
Function Email(Region As String) As String
    If Region = Atlantic Then
        Email = "email1@gmail.com"
    ElseIf Region = West Then
        Email = "email2@gmail.com"
    ElseIf Region = Pacific Then
        Email = "email3@gmail.com"
    ElseIf Region = Ontario Then
        Email = "email4@gmail.com"
    ElseIf Region = Atlantic Then
        Email = "email5@gmail.com"
    ElseIf Region = Quebec Then
        Email = "email5@gmail.com"
    Else: Region = "x"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Need to see rest of code besides the function. Also, try `case` statement.

Comment: If you put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module you will get errors. All your comparisons are variables, unless they are globals they are all undefined. Also the `Else` should be `Email =` not `Region =`

Comment: Also you have two Atlantics only the first will return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is on the assumption that you're testing for literal strings eg. `"Atlantic"` and that you don't have a variable or string returning function elsewhere called `Atlantic`.

---

Fixing your existing code, it would end up looking something like this - (note, I've removed the 2nd Atlantic check) -

```
Function Email(Region As String) As String
    If Region = "Atlantic" Then
        Email = "email1@gmail.com"
    ElseIf Region = "West" Then
        Email = "email2@gmail.com"
    ElseIf Region = "Pacific" Then
        Email = "email3@gmail.com"
    ElseIf Region = "Ontario" Then
        Email = "email4@gmail.com"
    ElseIf Region = "Quebec" Then
        Email = "email5@gmail.com"
    Else: Email = "x"
    End If
End Function
```

A somewhat easier to read method would be to use `Select Case`:

```
Function Email(Region As String) As String
    Select Case Region
    Case "Atlantic"
        Email = "email1@gmail.com"
    Case "West"
        Email = "email2@gmail.com"
    Case "Pacific"
        Email = "email3@gmail.com"
    Case "Ontario"
        Email = "email4@gmail.com"
    Case "Quebec"
        Email = "email5@gmail.com"
    Case Else
        Email = "x"
    End Select
End Function
```